# What is the purpose of ByteBuffer's flip method? (And why is it called "flip"?)

Tags: java, flip, bytebuffer

Why does ByteBuffer's flip() method called "flip"? What is "flipped" here? According to apidoc, two successive flips won't restore original state, and multiple flips will probably tend `limit()` to become zero.

Can I "unflip" somehow to reuse bytes went out of a limit?

Can I concatenate tail to be flipped with some other data?

Comment: It "flips" the buffer from read to write (and vice versa). http://thushw.blogspot.com/2009/10/java-bytebuffer-how-does-this-work.html

Comment: @BrianRoach: It flips from read to write but is not as useful for write to read unless you are writing fixed-size structures. For flipping to write to read, use `reset` instead.

Comment: Remember to ask "objective" questions; or, at least, make the predominant question seem objective :D

Comment: @nneonneo - It was kinda non-question, wasn't really going to spend much time on explaining the details, hence just a comment and a link.

Comment: "According to apidoc, two successive flips won't restore original state, and multiple flips will probably tend limit() to become zero." — I'm struggling to find where this was originally referenced from.  It doesn't appear to be in the `ByteBuffer` Javadoc, so I'm guessing it comes from somewhere else.

Answer (score 154):

One fairly common use case for the `ByteBuffer` is to construct some data structure piece-by-piece and then write that whole structure to disk. `flip` is used to flip the `ByteBuffer` from "reading from I/O" (`put`ting) to "writing to I/O" (`get`ting): after a sequence of `put`s is used to fill the `ByteBuffer`, `flip` will set the limit of the buffer to the current position and reset the position to zero. This has the effect of making a future `get` or `write` from the buffer write all of what was `put` into the buffer and no more.

After finishing the `put`, you might want to reuse the `ByteBuffer` to construct another data structure. To "unflip" it, call `clear`. This resets the limit to the capacity (making all of the buffer usable), and the position to 0.

So, a typical usage scenario:

```
ByteBuffer b = new ByteBuffer(1024);
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    b.clear();
    b.put(header[i]);
    b.put(data[i]);
    b.flip();
    out.write(b);
}
```

Comment: A `WritableByteChannel`, such as `FileChannel` or `SocketChannel`.

Comment: Or anything else that has a `write(ByteBuffer)` method.  (It is not really relevant what its type is ...)

Comment: It should `Buffer.clear` which reset limit to capacity and position to 0. `Buffer.reset` reset only position to `mark`.

Comment: @KelvinNg: You're right; I've amended the answer to reflect this. Thanks for the nice catch!

Comment: In some scenarios (you have "unwritten" bytes left in the buffer, if for example the consumer can only consume 4 bytes at once) you may also want to use `compact()` which moves them to the beginning of the buffer so that you can continue reading bytes into the buffer after them.

Comment: @AdamHughes second loop iteration reuses the cleared buffer. Having the clear at the end of the loop is also possible (but still has one clear call too many)

Comment: @nneonneo: How does "reading" means (putting) and "writing" means (getting)? E.g. when we use `put` you write data into buffer.

Comment: @user963241: read *from* I/O into buffer, write *from* buffer into I/O.

Comment: @KelvinNg Mark and reset are for `InputStreams`, not buffers.

Comment: @user207421 OP fixed the bug in his code snippet  at revision 2 https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14793037/revisions#

Answer (score 15):

Flip assigns the current position value to the limit property and sets the position property to `0`. Flip is useful to drain only active elements from a buffer.

For example, below program prints "hello" instead of empty elements of the buffer. Method calls `limit` and `position` can be replaced with `flip`.

```
CharBuffer cbuff = CharBuffer.allocate(40);
cbuff.put("hello"); 
// These two lines below are what flip does
cbuff.limit(cbuff.position());
cbuff.position(0);
    
while(cbuff.hasRemaining()) {
    System.out.println(cbuff.get());
}
```

See http://www.zoftino.com/java-nio-tutorial for more information on buffers and channels.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the very extensive coverage! It's so great when sources are included.  The java API docs seemed to use the word 'flip' without explanation, as if it were a common computer science term, but  obviously a few people (including me) haven't found that to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

*flip()* method makes a buffer ready for a new sequence of channel-write or relative get operations: It sets the limit to the current position and then sets the position to zero.

Buffer keeps track of the data written into it. Post writing, *flip()* method is called to switch from writing to reading mode.

Answer (score 1):

A buffer has a fixed `capacity`; it maintains 2 pointers: `start` and `end`. `get()` returns the byte at the `start` position and increments `start`. `put()` puts the byte at the `end` position and increments `end`. No `flip()`!

Comment: [[citation needed]] (I haven't heard these complaints about `ByteBuffer`). Also, the docs say there's only a "current position", not a "start" and "end".

Comment: I have heard, you can take my word for it.

Comment: So, what are the complaints? If you have some personal grievance that's OK too, but it does not do to just say "X API sucks, people said so".

Comment: Posting that link is literally all you had to do in the first place. I never accused you of lying, I merely asked you to elaborate on the source and the nature of the complaints.

Comment: this is just a place where people offer their help voluntarily, with the proper amount of effort they choose to. I do not need to expand each answer into a well researched academic paper.

Comment: and this is also a place where people will not take someone's word unless it sounds credible.

Comment: You don't even need to give sources. It is blatantly obvious that ByteBuffer is ill designed. flip does not fill a purpose, it just introduces a source of bugs when you forget to flip. If they felt an uncontrollable urge to put it in, at least make flipped and unflipped ByteBuffers different classes, so the type system can catch the bugs.

Comment: I respect people who offer criticism of standards despite the entrenchment of that standard. +1 +1 +1.

Comment: `flip` sounds like the buffer direction is reversed.  They need a verb to represent changing mode; `switch` is a keyword, so it's invalid, and `shift` has a whole other meaning in a bit-based context.  `swap` or `change` are better choices than `flip`.

Comment: There is nothing here that answers the question.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

`compact` is the inverse of `flip` for the general use case.

```
buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(...);  // create
buf.put(...);   // write
buf.flip();     // get ready to read
buf.get(...);   // read some of the data
buf.compact();  // delete the read data and get ready to write again
```