# Create AIScene instance from the file's content

Tags: spring, lwjgl, assimp

I'm writing a Java web service where it is possible to upload a 3D object, operate on it and store it.

What I'm trying to do is creating an `AIScene` instance using a `byte[]` as an input parameter which is the file itself (it's content).

I have found no way to do this in the docs, all import methods require a path.

Right now I'm taking a look at both the `lwjgl` java version of Assimp as well as the C++ version. It doesn't matter which one is used to solve the issue.

Edit: the code I'm trying to get done:

```
@Override
public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
    AIFileIO fileIo = AIFileIO.create();
    AIFileOpenProcI fileOpenProc = new AIFileOpenProc() {
        public long invoke(long pFileIO, long fileName, long openMode) {
            AIFile aiFile = AIFile.create();
            final ByteBuffer data;

            try {
                data = ByteBuffer.wrap(file.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            AIFileReadProcI fileReadProc = new AIFileReadProc() {
                public long invoke(long pFile, long pBuffer, long size, long count) {
                    long max = Math.min(data.remaining(), size * count);
                    memCopy(memAddress(data) + data.position(), pBuffer, max);
                    return max;
                }
            };
            AIFileSeekI fileSeekProc = new AIFileSeek() {
                public int invoke(long pFile, long offset, int origin) {
                    if (origin == Assimp.aiOrigin_CUR) {
                        data.position(data.position() + (int) offset);
                    } else if (origin == Assimp.aiOrigin_SET) {
                        data.position((int) offset);
                    } else if (origin == Assimp.aiOrigin_END) {
                        data.position(data.limit() + (int) offset);
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            };
            AIFileTellProcI fileTellProc = new AIFileTellProc() {
                public long invoke(long pFile) {
                    return data.limit();
                }
            };
            aiFile.ReadProc(fileReadProc);
            aiFile.SeekProc(fileSeekProc);
            aiFile.FileSizeProc(fileTellProc);
            return aiFile.address();
        }
    };
    AIFileCloseProcI fileCloseProc = new AIFileCloseProc() {
        public void invoke(long pFileIO, long pFile) {
            /* Nothing to do */
        }
    };
    fileIo.set(fileOpenProc, fileCloseProc, NULL);
    AIScene scene = aiImportFileEx(file.getName(),
            aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices | aiProcess_Triangulate, fileIo); // ISSUE HERE. file.getName() is not a path, just a name. so is getOriginalName() in my case. 

    try{
        Long id = scene.mMeshes().get(0);
        AIMesh mesh = AIMesh.create(id);
        AIVector3D vertex = mesh.mVertices().get(0);

        return mesh.mName().toString() + ": " + (vertex.x() + " " + vertex.y() + " " + vertex.z());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "fail";
}
```

When debugging the method I get an access violation in the method that binds to the native:

```
public static long naiImportFileEx(long pFile, int pFlags, long pFS)
```

this is the message:

> #
>
> ## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> #
>
> ## EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007400125d, pid=6400, tid=0x0000000000003058
>
> #
>
> ## JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_201-b09) (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
>
> ## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.201-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> ## Problematic frame:
>
> ## V  [jvm.dll+0x1e125d]
>
> #
>
> ## Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> #
>
> ## An error report file with more information is saved as:
>
> ## C:\Users\ragos\IdeaProjects\objectstore3d\hs_err_pid6400.log
>
> #
>
> ## If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>
> ## http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>
> #

Comment: Thank you for the comment but here https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/475e51d157e7826bdcbc0d88e6a73b1764960e0a/code/Assimp.cpp#L192 it shows that the underlying implementation uses the file's path anyway. The defined buffer is a custom IO system. As such it causes read access violation in my code because I have no valid file path coming from Spring's `MultipartFile`. Did I miss something? I'm adding my code to the question. Largely the same as the one you linked though except getting the data.

Comment: Then it really shouldn't be the problem. 
Could you help me on where did I mess up? I changed the code starting from my lines 8-10, because `MultipartFile` just passes the object and I already have it's content as a `byte[]`.

Comment: `public static long naiImportFileEx(long pFile, int pFlags, long pFS)` in this method I get the access violation, I add that to the question as well in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if we use the `aiImportFileFromMemory` method.

The approach I wanted to follow was copied from a github demo and actually copies the buffer around unnecessarily.

The reason for the access violation was the use of indirect buffers (for more info why that is a problem, check [this](https://tutorials.techmytalk.com/2014/11/03/java-nio-buffer/) out).

The solution is not nearly as complicated as the code I initially pasted:

```
@Override
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer((int) file.getSize());
        buffer.put(file.getBytes());
        buffer.flip();
        AIScene scene = Assimp.aiImportFileFromMemory(buffer,aiProcess_Triangulate, (ByteBuffer) null);
        Long id = scene.mMeshes().get(0);
        AIMesh mesh = AIMesh.create(id);
        AIVector3D vertex = mesh.mVertices().get(0);
        return mesh.mName().dataString() + ": " + (vertex.x() + " " + vertex.y() + " " + vertex.z());
    }
```

Here I create a **direct** buffer with the appropriate size, load the data and **[flip it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792968/what-is-the-purpose-of-bytebuffers-flip-method-and-why-is-it-called-flip)** (this part is a must.) After that let Assimp do its magic so you get pointers to the structure. With the `return` statement I just check if I got the valid data.

**edit**

As in the comments it was pointed out, this implementation is limited to a single file upload and assumes it gets everything that is necessary from that one `MultipartFile`, it won't work well with referenced formats. See [docs](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/cimport_8h.html#affea94ac388f95baf0312f3140710037) for more detail.

The demo that was linked in the question's comments which was used in the question as a base has a different use case to my original one.

Comment: Thank you for the input. The service assumed single file uploads, in my case it worked with an obj (because I had only one file, no `.mtl` and whatnot). I'll take a note in the answer in case someone stumbles upon this.

Comment: However in this case I'll think about solving the referencing issue too. This is a practice project after all.